# Hibernate/JPA - How to find all records, that match the pairs of given parameters, when they are not the primary key?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Consider a class `Car`

```
@Entity
class Car{
    @Id
    private UUID id; // primary key- this is the only thing that can't change.
    
    private String name;
    
    private String brand;
    
    private string model;
    
    @Data
    public static class Key{
        private String brand;
        private String model;
    }
}
```

There is a `List.of(new Key("brand1","model1"), new Key("brand2","model2"))`.
How is it possible to find all those given cars by those keys?

Is it doable with only JPA methods? Do I need to write native query? Can I modify something (besides primary key) in order to do it correctly?

I went to the direction of `@EmbeddedId` and then use the JPA method `findAllById(Collection ..)` which would be the naïve solution, but it's impossible since it must be the primary key in order to work.

Comment: you can use the @query annotation to construct your query, that way you will have more control.

Comment: @HassanLiasu got an example?

Comment: i wiil try to come up with one.